# Why do we need unsigned char for Huffman tree code

Tags: c, tree, huffman-code

I am trying to create a Huffman tree the question I read is very strange for me, it is as follows:

> Given the following data structure:
>
> ```
> struct huffman
> {
>     unsigned char sym;              /* symbol */
>     struct huffman *left, *right;   /* left and right subtrees */
> };
> ```
>
> write a program that takes the name of a binary file as sole argument,
>   builds the Huffman tree of that file assuming that atoms (elementary
>   symbols) are 8-bit unsigned characters, and prints the tree as well as
>   the dictionary.
>   allocations must be done using nothing else than
>   malloc(), and sorting can be done using qsort().

Here the thing which confuses me is that  to write a program to create a huffman tree we just need to do following things:

1. We need to take a frequency array (That could be `Farray[]={.......}`)
2. Sort it and add the two smallest nodes to form a tree until it don't left 1 final node(which is head).

Now the question is here: why and where do we need those unsigned char data? (what type of unsigned char data this question want, I think only frequency is enough to display a Huffman tree)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you purely want to display the *shape* of the tree, then yes, you just need to build it. However, for it to be of any use whatsoever you need to know what *original* symbol each node represents.

Imagine your input symbols are [ABCD]. An imaginary Huffman tree/dictionary might look like this:

```
         ( )
        /   \              A = 1
      ( )   (A)            B = 00
     /   \                 C = 010
   (B)   ( )               D = 011
        /   \
      (C)   (D)
```

If you don't store `sym`, it looks like this:

```
         ( )
        /   \              A = ?
      ( )   ( )            B = ?
     /   \                 C = ?
   ( )   ( )               D = ?
        /   \
      ( )   ( )
```

Not very useful, that, is it?

Edit 2: The missing step in the plan is step 0: build the frequency array from the file (somehow I missed that you don't need to actually encode the file too). This isn't part of the actual Huffman algorithm itself and I couldn't find a decent example to link to, so here's a rough idea:

```
FILE *input = fopen("inputfile", "rb");
int freq[256] = {0};
int c;
while ((c = fgetc(input)) != EOF)
    freq[c]++;
fclose(input);

/* do Huffman algorithm  */
...
```

Now, that still needs improving since it neither uses `malloc()` nor takes a filename as an argument, but it's not *my* homework ;)

Comment: You mean if i just have to print the tree, I just need the frequencies (like FArray[]={....} and then sort them and add the minimum nodes) and print that but if i have to encode that to find the compression ratio, length of each frequency element etc. then i need that a bit unsigned char (which this question asks me to take aa sole argument) , Am i Right ?

Comment: so you mean as a sole argument there must be a file called file.txt in which i must have something like this a=23 b=45 c=82 etc. Am i right ?

Comment: @user3085082 No, the file would contain "aaabccbbabbaccababacab..." You have to count the frequency of each symbol as part of reading the input.

Comment: Then if I have this type of input in the file then how i will count the frequency of the symbols "aaabccbbabbaccababacab..." ? Frequencies are supposed to be given by us to create huffman tree.It's quiet confusing

Comment: @user3085082 Allocate a array of integers the size of your alphabet(256). Set them all to zero. For each symbol that you read from the file, increment the count for that symbol by one. Once you've read the last symbol from the file, _that's_ your frequency array.

Comment: Actually i read from this link http://www.programminglogic.com/implementing-huffman-coding-in-c/ and after that i am in confusion , here they take a input file called "Input.txt" in which they have a=00011 b= 000101 c=00011 etc. and they have decalred frequencies in the code like this int englishLetterFrequencies [27] = {81, 15..} , That creates confusion in my mind.And you are talking abut something "aabbccabbc" etc in the "Input.txt" file.Please help me in removing this confusion

Comment: @user3085082 No, that "a=0011 b=011011" down the page is the _dictionary_ for that tree i.e. `symbol = Huffman code`. The "Input.txt" in for that _tree_ is the thousands of English-language texts that were analysed to count the letter frequencies. Because these are known they can use a stored version. In your case the data isn't English text, so you _don't know_ the frequencies beforehand, thus you have to count them yourself - you then have to read the file a second time to actually encode it.

Comment: @Notlikethis so as a conclusion, the way you telling me to do is Inside the InputFile.txt, I should have something like this "abcde" and in my code i have to take ArrayFreq[5]={0}; and then read the characters using a count variable (count++ for each coming alphabet and for each alphabet encountered will have frequency equal to the corresponding value of that "count" variable obtained).as an example for "abcde" the corresponding frequency will be "1,2,3,4,5" (because the counter start at "a" =1 and count++ for next character until the last character). Am i right ? Big Thanks for helping hand

Comment: @Notlikethis  Or you mean to say that we have to take into account how many times each character repeats in the character sequence  "aaabccbbabb"so that the number of repetition of a character will be it's frequency,here for example freq of "a" is "4". Or the previous comment is correct ??(where we just do count++ until the end and the value of count is frequency for that alphabet), which one you meant to say is correct ?

Comment: That's right, you count the number of times each character appears. I've added an example because I can't really explain it any better.

Comment: It's the best solution i say, thanks for this big help. The question was confusing but you explained well,now It's fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's a while since I did this, but I think the generated "dictionary" is required to **encode** data, while the "tree" is used to **decode** it. Of course, you can always build one from the other.

While decoding, you traverse the tree (left/right, according to successive input bits), and when you hit a terminal node (null pointer) then the 'sym' in the node is the output value.

Comment: Suppose if i don't need to print the dictionary, then do i need that 8 bit unsigned char? what exactly this line of the question mean "write a program that takes the name of a binary file as sole argument, builds the Huffman tree of that file assuming that atoms (elementary symbols) are 8-bit unsigned characters" THIS i am not able to understan, It's confusing , please help in explaining me

Comment: @user3085082 the unsigned chars are your input data: they're what you're counting the frequency _of_.

Comment: @Notlikethat so you mean as a sole argument there must be a file called file.txt in which i must have something like this a=23 b=45 c=82 etc. Am i right ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually data compression is divided into 2 big steps; given a stream of data:

- evaluate the probability that a given symbol will appear in the stream, in other words you evaluate how frequent a symbol appears in a dataset
- once you have studied the occurences and created your table with symbols associated with a probability, you need to encode the symbols according their probability, to achieve this magic you create a dictionary were the original symbol is often times just replaced with another symbol that is much smaller in size, especially true for symbols that are frequently used in the dataset, the dictionary keeps track of this substitutions for both the encoding and decoding phase. Hoffman gives you an algorithm to automate this process and get a fairly good result.

In practice it's a little bit more complicated than this, because trees are involved, but the main purpose is always to build the dictionary.

There is a complete [tutorial here](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/iL18T05o/).